# Syncing Metadata output from Datafactory in SQL Server database error using stored procedure: Json - Unexpected character 'S' is found at position 0

Tags: json, sql-server, database, azure-data-factory, ssms-2017

I am getting this error while trying to write the metadata output from DataFactory to a SQL Server database.

> "errorCode": "2402",
> "message": "Execution failed against SQL Server.
> SQL error number: 13609.
> Error Message: JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'S' is found at position 0."

I am using a stored procedure in the SQL Server database.

Metadata output:

```
{
        "childItems": [
            {
                "name": "DemoFile1",
                "type": "File"
            },
            {
                "name": "DemoFile2",
                "type": "File"
            } ]
       "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime",
       "executionDuration": 0
}
```

Procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prod1
    @parameter1 NVARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1] ([name], [type])
        SELECT
            name, type
        FROM 
            OPENJSON(@parameter1)
                WITH (
                      name NVARCHAR(max) '$.name',
                      type NVARCHAR(max) '$.type'
                     ) AS jsonValues
END
```

TIA!

Comment: [Edit] the question and tag the DBMS you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

Few things were missing:

1. Curly brackets { and }.
2. A comma `],`
3. `OPENJSON(@parameter1, '$.childItems')` second parameter.

You can always check if it is a well-formed JSON via T-SQL `ISJSON()` function.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @parameter1 NVARCHAR(max) = 
N'{
    "childItems": [
        {
            "name": "DemoFile1",
            "type": "File"
        },
        {
            "name": "DemoFile2",
            "type": "File"
        }
    ],
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime",
    "executionDuration": 0
}';

IF ISJSON(@parameter1) = 1
    SELECT name, type
    FROM OPENJSON(@parameter1, '$.childItems')
    WITH (
        name NVARCHAR(max) '$.name',
        type NVARCHAR(max) '$.type'
    ) AS jsonValues
ELSE
    THROW 50000,'JSON is not well-formed',1;
```

**Output**

```
+-----------+------+
|   name    | type |
+-----------+------+
| DemoFile1 | File |
| DemoFile2 | File |
+-----------+------+
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. But I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I have updated the input with the exact input, which I am getting from the system. I want the output exactly as you have posted.

Comment: I updated the answer. While asking a question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. It is copied as-is to SSMS, and will be runnable there.

Answer (score 1):

Your json structure is wrong and your error cause of that. Actually you missed `{` and `}` in your json should be like below:

```
{"childItems": [ { "name": "DemoFile1", "type": "File" }, { "name": "DemoFile2", "type": "File" } ]}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I have updated the input with the exact input, which I am getting from the system. Please have a relook.